# How to define an array of strings in TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "address": ["line1", "line2", "line3"]
}
```

How to define `address` in an interface? the number of elements in the array is not fixed.

Comment: I strongly suggest reading the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).

Answer (score 220, accepted):

```js
interface Addressable {
  address: string[];
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for a well-named interface.

Comment: As an extension, if you have a custom interface lets say `Customer` and you need to have another parent interface which should have List then it would be like `Customer[]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you explain more why the interface name is good?

Comment: @Ooker because it is an adjective. It describes a capability or behavior as opposed to a lineage.

Answer (score 27):

An array is a special type of data type which can store multiple values of different data types sequentially using a special syntax.

TypeScript supports arrays, similar to JavaScript. There are two ways to declare an array:

1. Using square brackets. This method is similar to how you would declare arrays in JavaScript.

```
let fruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
```

2. Using a generic array type, Array.

```
let fruits: Array<string> = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
```

Both methods produce the same output.

Of course, you can always initialize an array like shown below, but you will not get the advantage of TypeScript's type system.

```
let arr = [1, 3, 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', true, false];
```

[Source](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-array)

Answer (score 8):

It's simple as this:

```
address: string[]
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the answer I came here for:

```
enum Lines {
  "line1",
  "line2",
  "line3",
}

interface Addressable {
   address: keyof typeof Lines;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
{ address: Array<string> }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is something like:

```
type yourtype = { [key: string]: string[] }
```

Comment: This would define a type of an **object** with property keys as strings, each of which would hold a value of a string array, which is not what OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how the cool kids do it nowadays.

```
export type stringArray = [string][number][];
```

Explanation:

`[string]` creates a tuple of string

`[number]` cast the tuple into a string

`[]` declares it as an array

For non believers, here is the proof:

[image]

Comment: What is better about this than just using `String[]` ? (Aside from it not being as cool)

Comment: it has nothing better than `string[]` other than being less readable. but at least you learn about type casting in Typescript.